# Creating SQL Server instance via powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've been looking for a way to create a SQL Server instance and then create and configure a database via PowerShell. I have found ways to create databases, but is there a way to create SQL Server instances?

Comment: "Create an instance" means **installing** SQL Server again (from the installation media) - with a new, unique instance name. This can be done silently, by providing all the necessary answers in an "options file"

Comment: This is what I want. I want to install a new instance via powershell. Could you possibly provide a link to somewhere where I can get this information?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver15 - or just Google for it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a [`Configuration.ini`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver15) file created, whether it's from a previous manual install or if you've generated it yourself, you can easily install SQL server as you want with the options defined in `Configuration.ini`:

```
Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=MyConfigurationFile.INI
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at SqlServerDsc?

After that https://dbatools.io/ is pretty much the standard for all your SQL PowerShell needs.